# How to delete an object without having access to it?

Tags: c++, object, visual-c++, memory-management

I know that whenever I create a new object for a class, that object is stored in memory.  I also know that in creating that object, it can only be accessed within the set of braces it is created in (Scope visibility). I need to find a way to delete that object outside of the braces it is created in. I have looked at smart pointers briefly, and it might be what I want to use?  I'm assuming it is, I just don't know for sure.  If a smart pointer can satisfy my needs, would someone please provide me with an example of how to use a smart pointer to access an object outside of where it has been created?  Thanks :)

EDIT:

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class ModernWarfare2
{
    //my class
    ModernWarfare2();
};


DWORD XamHook(DWORD r3, DWORD r4, DWORD r5)
{
    switch(XamGetCurrentTitleId())//a function that tells what game is being played
    {
    case Xbox360Dashboard://if i were to exit the game mw2
        {
            if(CODAllocated)//a boolean
            {
                //free the memory of the previous cod game
                if(MW2Allocated)//another boolean
                {
                    delete[] MW2;//gives me an error because i dont have access to MW2
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    case COD_MW2:
        {
            if(!CODAllocated)
            {
                if(!MW2Allocated)
                {
                    ModernWarfare2 *MW2 = new ModernWarfare2();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return XamInputGetState(r3,r4,r5);
}
```

How do I fix my issue?

Comment: _"I also know that in creating that object, the object can only be accessed within the set of braces it is created in."_ Not necessarily.

Comment: I guess what I am asking then, how do I access it outside of there?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [**XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I think you need to provide a code example because I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added a code example of what I'm trying to do.  Sorry for lacking visual representation.

Comment: It's not a very good example, since you give zero indication as to what `MW2` is.

Comment: MW2 is an object created for the class ModernWarfare2.

Answer (score 5):

> I also know that in creating that object, the object can only be accessed within the set of braces it is created in.

Not necessarily; that's only true when you construct objects with automatic storage duration, like this:

```
void foo()
{
    T obj;
}
```

Such objects, yes, go out of scope.

Objects you allocate dynamically do *not*:

```
void foo()
{
    T* obj = new T();
}
```

This is a memory leak because you never destroy `*obj`; however, you can access it from pretty much wherever you like:

```
T* foo()
{
   return new T();
}

void bar()
{
   T* obj = foo();
   // yay!
}
```

or:

```
T* obj = nullptr;

void foo()
{
   obj = new T();
}

void bar()
{
   // do stuff with *obj
}

void baz()
{
   foo();
   bar();
}
```

This all gets dangerous and messy because you end up with *spaghetti code* in which the lifetime of the dynamically-allocated object is unclear, and in the examples above I *still* haven't approached the topic of eventually destroying the object. You have to be really careful not to destroy it whilst you're still using it.

This is where smart pointers come in, but if you want a tutorial on using smart pointers I'm going to have to refer you back to your C++11 book.

Answer (score 1):

"I also know that in creating that object, the object can only be accessed within the set of braces it is created in." - This depends on how you create the object.

Example 1 (can't be accessed outside braces):

```
void func(void)
{
    Object obj("foo", "bar");
}
```

Example 2 (can be accessed outside braces):

```
Object* func(void)
{
    Object* obj = new Object("foo", "bar");
    return obj;
}
```

Example 2 can be deleted using the keyword delete.

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for more information on pointers.
I haven't personally found a use for smart pointers but MSDN has good information on the topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx)

Comment: Why would you ever write `Object obj = Object();`?

Comment: Because you're writing C# at the time of answering this question and messed up ;) Thanks for pointing that one out.

Answer (score 0):

By creating MW2 with

```
{
    ModernWarfare2 *MW2 = new ModernWarfare2();
}
```

I was not able to reference MW2 elsewhere.  By doing this, I can create it and delete it in two different spots:

```
class ModernWarfare2
{
    //my class
    ModernWarfare2();
};

ModernWarfare2 *MW2 = NULL;

DWORD XamHook(DWORD r3, DWORD r4, DWORD r5)
{
    switch(XamGetCurrentTitleId())//a function that tells what game is being played
    {
    case Xbox360Dashboard://if i were to exit the game mw2
        {
            if(CODAllocated)//a boolean
            {
                //free the memory of the previous cod game
                if(MW2Allocated)//another boolean
                {
                    delete MW2;//gives me an error because i dont have access to MW2
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    case COD_MW2:
        {
            if(!CODAllocated)
            {
                if(!MW2Allocated)
                {
                    if(MW2 == NULL)
                    {
                        MW2 = new ModernWarfare2();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return XamInputGetState(r3,r4,r5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is basic design pattern
Make the data and the functions members of a class

```
class SomeHandler
{
public:
    void Acquire( /* some source */ );
    void DoSomething( /* eventual parameters */ );
    bool TrySomething(); // returns true if successful
private:
    void internalFunction();

    bool inGoodState;
    SomeType dataINeed;
    SomeOtherType otherData;
};

void SomeHandler::Acquire( /**/ ) 
{
    // implement like this
}
```

now the functions can access the all the data

the use it like

```
int main()
{
    SomeHandler h;

    h.Acquire();
    if( h.TrySomething() )
    {
        h.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code snippet, You have to save your pointer MW2 for 
future so that you can delete the pointer.

I would suggest you to change

```
if(!MW2Allocated)
```

to

```
if(!MW2)
```

so that you don't have to create another variable for saving the reference to your allocated memory
Offcourse you have to move

```
ModernWarfare2 *MW2
```

to a larger scope (move it to the scope same as MW2Allocated) and initialize it to NULL.
Use "nullptr" instead of "NULL" if you are using C++11 supported compiler.

Also makesure you use

```
delete
```

instead of

```
delete[]
```

since this is not an array allocation

I don't think you can use smart pointers to skip saving your reference to the allocated memory,
since they are meant to make the memory deletion automatic or to make sure two deletion doesn't occur
for the same memory.
Refer to 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541067/Cplusplus-Smart-Pointers
for a good explanation about smart pointers